# About 5% of clients receive a different start & end time for the same seminar in their mail. Very strange?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtpclient

So I've ran through my C# code line per line and have looked at the message being filled up with data etc. and it all works as expected. The time being sent  in the mail equals the time stored in the Database. This is all for **ONE AND THE SAME** seminar, so it would be expected all outgoing mails are exactly the same. I've also tried sending the emails to my email address, for which I always get the correct time (that correlates to the time in the Database). Names, seminar speakers, all the other data is 100% correct over all clients. However, somehow, about 5% of clients receive an email where the date is correct, but the time is different!

The Time gets set like this:

```
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Brussels:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", DatumStart));
                                            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", DateTime.UtcNow));
                                            str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND;TZID=Europe/Brussels:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmss}", DatumStop));
```

And the time is a TimeSpan object:

```
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.Parse(Reader["Seminarie_start"].ToString());
                                                DatumStart += time;
```

Our clients (and us) are all in the same country that uses the UTC+1:00 timezone (Europe/Brussels).

Output (example) looks like this:

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20171107T190000
DTSTAMP:20171106T132718
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Brussels:20171107T210000
```

Where you can see the DTSTART is set for 19:00 and DTEND is set for 21:00 which is correct in the Database. The DTSTAMP time & date is the time & date on which I ran my code (few hours ago, I've been looking ever since) in **DateTime.UtcNow** (so here it says 13:27:18 but I ran the code at 14:27:18 UTC+1 time).

Very strange why some clients receive an email with a different hour, if in my code the email is created in the exact same way every time. Could it be that their local settings are in a different Timezone somehow, since that is also the **ONLY** difference in the emails being sent out?

Comment: Windows has quite a few TZ's which are UTC+1. I'd check what the TZ's of those with a different time are. (I'd guess that the difference between the UTC+1 zones is the dates clock changes happen.)

Comment: Most likely on their end, then? What's the difference in UTC+1 timezones then? Daylight Savings Time?

Comment: Netherlands Daylight Savings Time starts two weeks before the DST here in the US. Even dates with the same UTC offset can start DST at different times.

Comment: I see, thank you I will look into it further and will ask more info from the clients receiving the emails with a wrong hour! What if the problem persists and is not linked to the DST differences? Say they have it in Januari as well? Could it be they have wrong/different local settings?

Comment: Do I read this correctly: The difference is not a random one but exactly one hour?

Comment: I'm wary of any code that converts something into a string just to be able to then `Parse` it back into a real data type.

Comment: @RossBush - it's a bit better coordinated between countries in [europe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_Time_in_Europe) (most switch at the same times of year)

Comment: @Fildor yes, it's in the .ics file for Outlook that like 5% of clients get a difference in hour :s So my best guess it's most likely on their end/in their settings.